# URL Rewriterule works for external redirect but not with internal redirect

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I am having a problem with my .htaccess since it's acting weird in some way. My url is

```
http://my_domain.com/best_apps/my_apps/login
```

and i wanted it to be redirected internally using mod rewrite to

```
http://my_domain.com/best_apps/index.php/login
```

Below is my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 ^(my_app)
RewriteRule ^(my_app)(.*)$ /best_apps/index.php$2 [L]
```

The weird behavior is that it doesn't work and displays a 404 error if the redirect is internal (the flag is `[L]`) but it does work and redirects to my login page properly if i do it externally (the flag is `[R=301,L]`).

Note: the rewrite should work in all pages of my application and not just for the login page.

Comment: What `URL` does your server report in the 404 (not found) error? It will help to find the problem...

Comment: nope... not my server or domain but my application.. i tried printing the requested url and it says:

*http://my_domain.com/best_apps/my_apps*


which i think means that the url werent successfully rewritten. but why does it work with external redirect?

thanks.

Comment: Hm, lets try to make the `RewriteRule` simple as possible: `RewriteRule ^my_app(/.*)$ /best_apps/index.php$1 [L]` - it should do the same as yours. I expect there are other rules causing the problem

Comment: thanks, Kamil.

i tried it but it didn't work. Now my domain/server is the one reporting the 404 error.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `RewriteRule ^beste_apps/(my_app)(.*)$ /best_apps/index.php$2 [L]`?

Comment: Hi @Gerben,

I've tried what you suggested but still it didn't work. The domain/server is reporting a 404 error.

Comment: What other rewrite rules do you have, and likewise do you have another .htaccess in your my_apps folder by chance?